# Flask - Query CSV and Pass Results to render_template()

Tags: flask

I have created two web pages - index and reports.
The index page contains an input box where the user can enter a Zip Code. When the submit button is pressed, the code reads in and queries a CSV file based on the Zip Code. The results are then passed to render_template.

When I run my code, all that displays on the reports page is the header row of the CSV file.
I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Below is a snippet of my app.py file

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')            
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/reports', methods=['POST'])  
def reports():
    zip_code = request.form.get('zip_code')
    df = pd.read_csv('real-estate.csv')
    myData = df[df['zip'] == zip_code] 
    return render_template('reports.html', zip_code=zip_code, myData=myData)
```

Below is the contents of my reports file.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}     
    <div class='container'>
       <h2>Real Estate Transactions</h2>
 
       <ul>
        {% for rec in myData %}
           <li>{{ rec }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) to iterate over the rows of the dataframe.

```
<ul>
  {% for key,value in myData.iterrows() -%}
  <li id="row-{{key}}">{{value}}</li>
  {% endfor -%}
</ul>
```

An example of a table would then look something like this.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for column in myData.columns -%}
      <th>{{column}}</th>
      {% endfor -%}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for key,value in myData.iterrows() -%}
    <tr id="row-{{key}}">
      {% for v in value.values -%}
      <td>{{v}}</td>
      {% endfor -%}
    </tr>
    {% endfor -%}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried your suggestions. Nothing displayed. Seems like myData is empty.

Comment: @KateMac Is it possible that your zip codes are integers and you are comparing a string to an integer? Try `zip_code = request.form.get('zip_code', type=int)` in your form value query.

Comment: I found my error. It doesn't like my filter.
If I use this: myData = pd.read_csv('real-estate.csv', usecols=cols)
the data displays just fine. 
So the issue is the query.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much.
I never thought of that lol